# Python script to find max coverage with min false positives

Tags: python, optimization

I have two datasets:

```
DF_EVENT (1 if Event happened for customer, 0 otherwise)
Customer Event
1        1
2        1
3        0
4        1

DF_HX (list of all products purchased by customer)
Customer Product_id
1        x
2        y
3        x
3        z
4        y
4        x
```

I want to identify a list of `Product_Id` from `DF_HX` that will provide the smallest number of Customers who would cover at least 95% of customers with `Event=1` in `DF_EVENT`.

In the example above, if I chose `Product_Id=x`, I'd capture 66% of events with a population of 3 customers (customers 1, 3 and 4 purchased product x). If I chose `Product_Id x and y`, I'd capture 100% of events with a population of 4 customers (customers 1, 2, 3 and 4 purchased product x and y).

Comment: Requests for code belong rather to Stack Overflow. Voting to migrate the question there.

Comment: Agree with @JanKukacka. This is more appropriate for the StackOverflow forum unless the OP can adjust the question.